# jQuery: Code syntax when comparing text across two separate elements

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, syntax

Can someone kindly tell me what is wrong with the syntax in the block of code below? In case it matters, I am trying to compare the text that displays in two separate elements when a new html page is loaded. When a match is found, I want to display the hidden element to be shown.
Thank you very much.

```
function showcategory() {
  var bcrumbtext = $("ol.breadcrumbs").text();
  var catname = $("li.cat").text(); 

  $(catname).each(function() {
    if($(this)===(bcrumbtext)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  )};
}
```

HTML snippet showing the 'breadcrumbs' list

```
    <nav class="sub-nav">
      <ol class="breadcrumbs">
        <li title="Home">
          <a href="myURL">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li title="InitialCategory">
          <a href="myURL">Category1</a>
        </li>
        <li title="Article1">
          <a href="myURL">Article1</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
```

HTML snippet showing 'category' list items and their children

```
  <ul class="category">
    <li class="cat" catid="360002246652">
      <a>Category1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section1a</a> 
    </li>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section1b</a> 
    </li>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section1c</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="category">
    <li class="cat" catid="360002246672">
      <a>Category2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section2a</a> 
    </li>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section2b</a> 
    </li>
    </li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002246652"  parentsecid="null" style="display: none;">
      <a href="myURL">section2c</a> 
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Basically, on every page that loads, I need to search text within the `li.cat` items and compare it to the text within the `ol.breadcrumbs` items. When a match is identified, I need to show all of the child section list items `(li class = "sec")` that are beneath THAT category.

(I now see that my initial attempt at getting the code right has multiple errors. Hopefully someone in the community can help me resolve it as I am not sure what to do here.)

Comment: You should fix your indentation so it's consistent and readable. Are you getting an error message when looking at the developer console (note, if you aren't looking at the developer console in your browser, you should, as it gives you diagnostic information about your Javascript)? I'm not sure what is in the text for the `li.cat` item, but you're treating it as and element selector when you say `$(catname)`. It's unclear whether you intend that. I'm also not sure why you have parentheses around `bcrumbtext` in the comparison, `$(this) === (bcrumbtext)` though it causes no harm.

Comment: It would help if you also showed some example HTML that this Javascript would be intended to process. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. I added some additional code. I see that my initial attempt at the jQuery is off. Perhaps someone in the community can set me straight.

Comment: Well, your indentation went from so-so to pretty bad. ;) So as I mentioned, your `$(catname)` is taking the text from your `li.cat` and treating it like a DOM element. However, now that you show your HTML, you have cat names of, for example, `section1c`. There are no elements with names like that. In addition, the ordered list has mutliple elements. These are not "selectable" in that you can't query the DOM to find out which list item is selected. So your `$("ol.breadcrums")` isn't returning just one of the list items. I'm back to wondering exactly what it is you are desiring to achieve.

Comment: As there are multiple issues with your jQuery, I think you should study your jQuery online a bit, get some of the basics down, then you can ask a more specific and clear question. As it stands, it looks like you're looking for someone to solve a broader problem but the problem isn't stated clearly.

Comment: for some reason, stack overflow was giving me an insane amount of trouble loading the code examples. i have posted many questions over time and have never had this amount of issue with code snippets -- the editor kept reporting that the code was not sufficiently indented to be represented as code, yet it was showing it as code in the editor. anyway -- i may try to post the question again at some point. between having to santize everything i post (since it is for a client and i cannot reveal *actual* content) and the struggle with the editor, I am simply exhausted. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to hear of all the troubles you've had on SO. One thing I've discovered when it comes to inserting code: the SO editor does not handle tab characters well. I recommend passing any source code through a tab expansion first, to get it to spaces, then insert it. You can have great looking code with tabs, then SO will make it ugly when inserted. I still recommend checking on some good jQuery tutorials.

Comment: Thanks again. I am constantly looking at tutorials and have actually made a fair amount of progress with my overall project. (I am building a dynamic hierarchical menu.) In general, I understand the logic of what I need to accomplish, but there are complexities to what I need to accomplish and sometimes the syntax and approach elude me. Anyway, I am trying to take a slightly more 'granular' approach to asking questions. Here is my latest inquiry:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448344/jquery-variables-to-compare-text-in-various-list-items