# jQuery: Variables to Compare text in various list items

Tags: jquery, list, variables, compare

If I have the following ordered list:

```
<ol class="breadcrumbs">
    <li title="Sbox">
        <a href="myURL">SANDBOX</a>
    </li>
    <li title="API Ref">
        <a href="myURL">API Reference</a>
    </li>
    <li title="Schemas">
        <a href="myURL">Schema Files</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I am able to 'harvest' the second child list item's text ('API Reference') by using this jQuery code:

```
var bcrumbtext = $("ol.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)").text();
```

If I then have *multiple* Unordered lists (6 to be exact) with the following structure:

```
<ul class="category">
    <li class="cat" catid="360002246652"><a>Getting Started</a></li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do X</a></li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do Y</a></li>
    <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do Z</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="category">
        <li class="cat" catid="360002246652"><a>API Reference</a></li>
        <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do X</a></li>
        <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do Y</a></li>
        <li class="sec" secid="360007910471" categoryid="360002246652" parentsecid="null"><a href="myURL">How to do Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I set up a variable that will allow me to successfully 'harvest' the text in the first list item (li class of 'cat') for EACH of the unordered lists?

My ultimate goal is to be able to compare the one 'bcrumbtext' value (in this particular case: 'API Reference') to the text value for EACH list item that has a class of 'cat'. (This .cat list item is always the first offspring in the 'category' UL.) Once a match is established, I will then need to change a CSS value, but that is the next step and I will handle that step in time. For the moment, I am just stuck on how to set up my second variable and execute the value comparisons.

Thanks in advance for any input you can provide.

---

Here is an updated code block. I am looking to show all `li.sec` list items falling under the particular `li.cat` with the matching text value. Note that the default 'display' property for `li.sec` is 'none'(hence my use of the 'show' method).

Somehow, this is still not working. No errors are showing up in the console, but the desired effect is not implemented:

```
var bcrumbtext = $("ol.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)").text();
    $("ul.category li.cat").each(function() { 
        if ($(this).text() == bcrumbtext) { 
        $(this).nextUntil('ul').show('li.sec');
     } 
 });
```

Comment: `$("ul.category li.cat").each(function() { if ($(this).text() == bcrumtext) { ...change CSS value... } })` This will iterate through each `li.cat` item in the `ul.category` and check the text of each `li.cat` item with `bcrumtext`.

Comment: Thank you very much @lurker. I think I am getting there. The code is not throwing errors, which is a great start. I still have not achieved the final effect I need though -- which is to show all 'li.sec' list items falling directly under the particular 'li.cat' with the matching text value. ('li.sec' has a default Display of 'none'.)
I appended some code to my original question. Perhaps you are able to identify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that the `.show()` method does not take an element selector as an argument. The [documentation for `.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) describes possible arguments.

In addition, knowing now what you want to achieve, rather than use `nextUntil` I'd use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/). The `nextUntil` relies on the placement of other HTML elements around the one of interest, which is an unnecessary dependency, and `.siblings()` suits this purpose well.

Note that retrieving the text from "ol.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)" will include any leading/trailing white space (*e.g.*, new line characters) that exist between `<li title="...">` and `</li>`. There are some new lines in there, so these need to be removed with `.trim()` before comparing.

Refactoring your attempt with these things in mind:

```
var bcrumbtext = $("ol.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)").text().trim();

$("ul.category li.cat").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == bcrumbtext) {
    $(this).siblings(".sec").show()
  } 
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbratch/v968zLkx/4/) to demonstrate that it works (click the Try button).

Comment: Again -- thanks so much for your help. Good catch regarding the `.show()`  method, and I agree with your suggestion about doing away with `nextUntil`.

Unfortunately though, the new code still does not work. No errors show up in the console, but the target `li.sec` items still do not display. 

Based on tireless attempts to debug on my end, my hunch is that something is off with the if-statement. The syntax may be fine, but somehow, the match between the `bcrumbtext` and the 'li.cat' is not being identified by all the processing, so the `.show()` never gets triggered. Ugh!

Comment: @Marconi you can easily add a `console.log(...)` for the variables you want to inspect.

Comment: @Marconi I updated my answer a little and added `.trim()` on the `bcrumbtext`. The reason is that  the `.text()` will include any leading or trailing newline or other whitespace characters that are in the text which need to be removed when comparing. Any newlines between the `<li ...>` and `</li>` are going to be part of the `.text()`. I added a fiddle link to demonstrate.

Comment: Bingo! It works. Thank you so much! The `trim()` is what did the trick. (Note that you did omit a closing semicolon after the line that ends with `show()`, but I put it in my code. I tried to add it to your response, but received an alert saying the edit queue is full.)

Now - one last thing if you do not mind: If I wanted a second variable to hold the `li.cat` text, how would I properly use it with the `each()` function? Here is the variable as I envision it:

`var cattext =  $("ul.category li.cat").text().trim();`

Comment: @Marconi the semicolon in Javascript is optional. You can see that from the working fiddle. :). Glad it worked. Your suggestion for `cattext` looks fine.

Comment: Thank you again Sir. 

I tried to implement the `cattext` variable but I keep getting an error that says `cattext` is not a function. Here is the line of code I use to call the variable along with the `each()` function.

`cattext.each(function() {`

I have tried to write the expression in a variety of ways, but keep getting the error. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @Marconi `cattext` the way you defined it is just a string. You didn't say how you intended to use it, so I would not have known that when I said it was ok. Strings do not support the `.each` method as that method applies to DOM elements. If you want to apply the `.each`, then you'd want `var catelement = $("ul.category li.cat")`. That refers to the DOM element. Then you can write `catelement.each(function() {...})`. `.text()` returns a string, and `.trim()` operates on strings.

Comment: Again -- thank you so much. Your input has been invaluable here.